# Powershell: Removing curly quotes in directory name

Tags: string, powershell, replace

This ought to be pretty straight forward, but I can't figure out why it isn't working.  I am trying to replace curly quotes (’,“,”) with regular quotes (',").  The quotes that are in directory name strings that are being read in.  I don't want to rename the directories.  I just want to change the string for further processing.

To test this, I created the following folders:

```
D:\Test
    Double Left “ Quote
    Double Right ” Quote
    Single ’ Quote
```

To test, I have this code:

```
count = 0

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\test' -Directory |
ForEach-Object {

    $name = $_.Name

    Write-Host $name

    if ($name.Contains("’")) {
        Write-Host "Single Curly Quote: $name"
        $name = $name -replace("’","'")
        Write-Host "Fixed: $name"
    }
    if ($name.Contains('“')) {
        Write-Host "Double Left Curly Quote: $name"
        $name = $name -replace('“','"')
        Write-Host "Fixed: $name"
    }
    if ($name.Contains('”')) {
        Write-Host "Single Right Curly Quote: $name"
        $name = $name -replace('”','"')
        Write-Host "Fixed: $name"
    }

    $count += 1

}

Write-Host $count
```

But when I run it, I get this result:

```
C:\Users\brian.w.williams> . 'C:\Users\brian.w.williams\Desktop\Test.ps1'
Double Left “ Quote
Double Right ” Quote
Single ’ Quote
3
```

It doesn't see the offending curly quotes.

I get the same result if I just have the straight replaces.  I put the extra code in just to try to figure out what is happening.

Any suggestions?

The code is running in Powershell 7 on a Windows 10 x64 computer.

I am expecting the curly quote to be replaced with the regular straight quote.

if I create a string variable that has the curly quotes in it instead of using the directory name value, the code works perfectly.

Comment: Works for me.  "count = 0" is missing a dollar sign in front.  As usual, the script has to be utf8-with-bom in powershell 5.1, without which would give your output.

Comment: The other possibility is the script is encoded in what notepad calls "ansi" and powershell 7 doesn't understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are more variants to the single- and double curly smartquotes, I would use a small helper function on top:

```
function Convert-SmartQuotes {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$Text
    )

    # return the given string with all curly quotes replaced by straight ones
    $Text -replace '[\u201C\u201D\u201E\u201F\u2033\u2036]', '"' -replace "[\u2018\u2019\u201A\u201B\u2032\u2035]", "'"
}
```

Then your code could be:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\test' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Convert-SmartQuotes $_.Name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some odd .net character quote classes.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions

Pi  Punctuation, Initial quote (may behave like Ps or Pe depending on usage)

Pf  Punctuation, Final quote (may behave like Ps or Pe depending on usage)

The single and double versions of each curly quote match the same way.  There is also a left single curly quote.  Ps or Pe didn't match for me.  Powershell also treats these as regular quotes in code, not left or right.

```
"‘" | select-string '\p{Pi}'

‘


'“' | select-string '\p{Pi}'   # also matches ‟

“


"’" | select-string '\p{Pf}'

’


'”' | select-string '\p{Pf}'

”
```

IsGeneralPunctuation (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Unicode_2000-206F_General_Punctuation) matches all of the curly quotes, single and double, as well as other punctuation in the 0x2000..0x206f range (112 items).

```
"’" | select-string '\p{IsGeneralPunctuation}'

’
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex pattern to match those 3 smart quotes and, using [replacement with a scriptblock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-with-a-script-block), you can replace them with the correct values stored in a hashtable, for example:

```
$map = @{
    "’" = "'"
    '”' = '"'
    '“' = '"'
}

@'
Double Left “ Quote
Double Right ” Quote
Single ’ Quote
'@ -replace '[\u201d\u2019\u201c]', { $map[$_.Value] }
```

Your code could be:

```bash
$map = @{
    "’" = "'"
    '”' = '"'
    '“' = '"'
}

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\test' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name -replace '[\u201d\u2019\u201c]', { $map[$_.Value] }
}
```

Comment: that's not going to rename them.   

This should work    

`Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\test' -Directory | Foreach-Object {    
    Rename-Item  -Path $_ -NewName $($_.Name -replace '[\u201d\u2019\u201c]', { $map[$_.Value] })    
}`

Comment: @sirtao The OP clearlt states _I don't want to rename the directories._

Comment: @Theo I'm apparently blind or dumb or both, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Directories**

```
C:\USERS\MEGAM\DESKTOP\PS-REPLACEQUOTES
│   Script.ps1
│
├───All “ - ” - ’ - ‘ Quotes
├───Double Left “ Quote
├───Double Right ” Quote
└───Single ’ Quote
```

**1st altenative - Code - Script.ps1** https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/Ps-ReplaceCurlyQuotes

```
& tree $PSScriptRoot /f

$names = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$patterns = @( # pattern, replace
    @("[`‘`’]", "`'"), 
    @("[`“`”]", "`"")
)

$names | ForEach-Object{ 
    $name = $_
    $patterns | ForEach-Object{
        $pattern = $_
        $name = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($name,$pattern[0],$pattern[1])
    }
    Write-Host "$_" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host " → " -NoNewline
    Write-Host "$name" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

**Output**
[image: output]

---

**2nd alternative - Code - Script2.ps1** https://github.com/JomaStackOverflowAnswers/Ps-ReplaceCurlyQuotes
Reusable function.

```
function Set-Quotes {
    param (
        [string]
        $Text
    )
    @( 
        @("[`‘`’]", "`'"), 
        @("[`“`”]", "`"")
    ) | ForEach-Object {
        $Text = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($Text, $_[0], $_[1])
    }
    return $Text
}

& tree $PSScriptRoot /f

$names = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$names | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host "$_" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host " → " -NoNewline
    Write-Host "$(Set-Quotes -Text $_)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```